# USB 2.0 not working in my Ubuntu 13.04 Dell XPS 13

Tags: usb, dell, usb-drive

I have Ubuntu 13.04 installed on my **Dell XPS 13 Ultrabook**.

I need to get the USB 2.0 port on the left side of the ultrabook to read my pendrive.

When I plug it in, nothing happens. It works fine with the USB 3.0 port on the right side though. My pendrive is 2.0, so this is really puzzling me.

How can I get my USB 2.0 port to recognize my pendrive?

(I need to do this in order to boot Windows 7 from my pendrive)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with my desktop, I use an AMD processor, Enabling the option IOMMU in the BIOS fixed it, if you have that option in the BIOS try it