# Dell XPS13 L321X USB3.0 not working

Tags: 16.04, usb

I'm fairly new to Linux and I recently installed 16.04 on my Dell XPS L321X and now my USB3.0 port (left side of laptop) no longer works. If I boot from a bootable USB stick then the port works as expected. but if I boot into my installation of 16.04 and plug in any USB stick or device such as my mouse it is not recognized/doesn't work.
I found [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/344964/usb-2-0-not-working-in-my-ubuntu-13-04-dell-xps-13) however that person's USB2.0 port (right side of laptop) wasn't working and my BIOS doesn't have an IOMMU option.
Can anyone suggest how I might be able to resolve this?

EDIT: When running Disks a USB stick does not show up when used with the right side USB3.0 port.

Comment: Does the USB show up in the program **Disks** when a drive is inserted? Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/998376/edit) your question and add the new information.

Comment: Have you turned off UEFI fast boot? It turns out the loading of USB drivers is somewhat slow. Fastboot with UEFI skips a lot of reinitialization, so you may not see a new device in a USB port.
UEFI fast boot, skips the old BIOS Power-on self-test (POST), assumes no changes to system